# Is it a good practices to link libstdc++ static?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, libstdc++

I recently got a position for developing C++ server application running in GNU/Linux and Unix including Solaris, HP-UX, and so on. Since my company is planning to rewrite everthing from scratch, I'm thinking about how to develop it using modern C++.

Unfortunately, due to it's closed-platform nature, it seems like that it is not always possible to get a descent libstdc++ runtime in client's machines. I know libstdc++ is backward compatible, but is sucks that I have to target GCC 3.4 or 4.2(in case of HP-UX), and their(Unix provider)'s compiler is [sucks](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Fortunately, it seems like some people claim that [linking libstdc++ statically is fine](https://lwn.net/Articles/549573) in a sence of legal things, and 
[someone](http://micro.nicholaswilson.me.uk/post/31855915892/rules-of-static-linking-libstdc-libc-libgcc) recommends it in a terms of technical way. However, I'm not sure if it is safe (in terms of legal and technical) to do that.

Is it a make sence to to link libstdc++ static? This product offers executable and shared library for third-party developer and it doesn't load any third-party shared library not in system's one.

Comment: Great question, I always wondered myself about the legal implications...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 50 cents:

I'm a big fan of linking stuff statically (especially on Windows), but the price is that in case there are bugs/security problem, you have to re-ship your product or offer an update. I'm reluctant to doing that in Linux/Unix, because you generally don't have binary compatibility over all Unix operating systems. If you compile for a target system, then it doesn't matter (except, again, you have to take care of bugs yourself with updates).

Performance wise, shared libraries have this little overhead of loading the libraries, which is ridiculously negligible nowadays.

Legally, you're fine (Disclaimer, I'm not a lawyer, you may want to consult your company's lawyer). GNU has an [exception](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html) on their Runtime libraries:

> The source code is distributed under the GNU General Public License
>   version 3, with the addition under section 7 of an exception described
>   in the “GCC Runtime Library Exception, version 3.1” as follows (or see
>   the file COPYING.RUNTIME)

If that wasn't the case, then no propietary products would have been ever available on Linux.

Also you might want to consider using the Clang compiler if you're concerned about licensing. It has a [very tolerant BSD license](https://clang.llvm.org/features.html). Well, since you're rewriting stuff from scratch.